# Python 2.3 for Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, 32bit-64bit, python-2.3

I have developed my application with some python scripts that was written in Python 2.3 *(Windows 32-bit OS)*

Now I need to give support for Windows 64-bit. But I can not find Python 2.3 for 64-bit.

I have installed Python 2.7 in 64-bit, but I'm facing some compatibility issues (2.3 vs. 2.7)

So, is there any Python 2.3 for Windows 64-bit.

Comment: 64 bit Windows didn't exist when Python 2.3 was released. You can run 32 bit Python on 64 bit Windows anyway, either do that, or update your code. (2.3 is pretty ancient after all.)

Comment: I think you're going to find it more and more difficult to find a version of python2.3 which plays nicely with your target platform.  How significant are the compatability issues?  Your best bet is to update your code to be python2.6 compatable (at least).

Comment: @all : How can i update? manually right? it is tedious

Comment: @PramodhTS -- Not as tedious and frustrating as trying to figure out how to install an ancient version of python every time you want to put your code on a different machine.

Comment: @mgilson: hmmmmmmmmmmm............... :-(

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issues trying to run 2.3 code in 2.7? Most of the changes between the two should be upward compatible.

Comment: Python 2 **is** forward compatible (which includes the step from 2.3 to 2.7). Compatibility breaks not until Python 3. So this is not the issue. What problems are you facing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Python 2.3 is not available in 64 bit for windows. Your best bet would be to run your scripts using Python 2.7 and to fix whatever compatibility issues you may have.